# DomPDF acting different in localhost than GoDaddy Hosting

Tags: laravel, localhost, hosting, dompdf

I have problem with DomPDF the problem is it works in localhost perfectly but when I try it in Hosting it gives me this error:

```
     ErrorException in Cpdf.php line 3547:
    Undefined index:
in Cpdf.php line 3547
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: ', '/home/imphusius/public_html/cafeconor/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/Cpdf.php', '3547', array('size' => '12')) in Cpdf.php line 3547
at Cpdf->getFontHeight('12') in CPDF.php line 809
at CPDF->get_font_height('/home/imphusius/public_html/cafeconor/vendor/dompdf/dompdf\lib\fonts\Times-Roman', '12') in FontMetrics.php line 352
at FontMetrics->getFontHeight('/home/imphusius/public_html/cafeconor/vendor/dompdf/dompdf\lib\fonts\Times-Roman', '12') in Text.php line 188
at Text->_layout_line() in Text.php line 362
at Text->reflow(object(Block)) in AbstractFrameDecorator.php line 801
at AbstractFrameDecorator->reflow(object(Block)) in Block.php line 738
at Block->reflow(null) in AbstractFrameDecorator.php line 801
at AbstractFrameDecorator->reflow() in Page.php line 133
at Page->reflow(null) in AbstractFrameDecorator.php line 801
```

Would anyone have idea where Error comes from and why?

Comment: Is this a deployment that you copied from local to GoDaddy? Could be a font metrics issue. Reset your font/font cache directories (both dompdf/lib/fonts by default) to the distribution state and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue some time ago on a different host. After experimenting a while turns out that clearing the host built-in cache and performing a `php artisan cache:clear` (maybe a `php artisan route:clear` could suffice) solved the problem. If this is your case too, i'd suggest to schedule this cache wipe using the Laravel cron jobs.
Let me know if it helped.